# Why does this note have two stems?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

[image]

I think this is a normal note but I'm not sure. Why is this note like this? Can you explain it please?

Answer (score 7):

This piece of music has two voices.  The note has two stems because the voices are playing the same note.  It looks like the lower voice holds the note (hence the tie) while the upper voice changes in the next measure.

Comment: How am i suppose to play this

Comment: If it's choir music then two voices are singing in unison.  On classical guitar we sometimes double the note, especially if it's one of the open strings (very common in guitar arrangements of baroque lute music).  For piano I would guess that you cannot play it twice.  I'd guess that the sheet music is merely indicating how the voices move.

Comment: @Melanie, is there a reason this was marked as the answer then unmarked?

Comment: The same can apply for a single voice, like a violin, where it would mean to play the note on two strings at the same time.

Comment: True, I see that in guitar music, but I would still call that 2 voices, a unison double stop